# How can I get ms precision in the Date.toString() call?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some performance profiling on a web app, and I'd like to be able to see how long it takes to execute sections of code.

I'm doing this by printing a date object to the console.

I can't seem to get the date object to print its time more precisely than down to the second.  Is this possible, without going so far as to get the ms since 1970 and calculating it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method of `Date` provides ms resolution:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toISOString();
```

Returns:

```
'2012-11-23T22:31:51.321Z'
```

But for timing sections of code, you're probably better off using [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.time) and [`console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.timeEnd).

Comment: console.time is perfect for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Date.now()`.

```
var start = Date.now();
```

This gives you time in milliseconds.

- [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) for `Date.now()`.

You can shim it if you're testing older implementations.

```
if (!Date.now)
    Date.now = function() {
        return +(new Date());
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're profiling your javascript code, then why not use the developer tools built into a modern browser?

Chrome has it's developer tools (press F-12)

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles

The Profiles panel lets you profile the execution time and memory usage of a web app or page. The Profiles panel includes two profilers: a CPU profiler and a Heap profiler. These help you to understand where resources are being spent, and so help you to optimize your code:

- The CPU profiler shows where execution time is spent in your page's
  JavaScript functions.
- The Heap profiler shows memory distribution by
  your page's JavaScript objects and related DOM nodes.

Other browser's have similar tools at your disposal and don't require additional code.

Comment: I'm really looking for a quick and dirty way of doing this.  Learning a tool is a bit more involved than I wanted to get.

Comment: It's **really** straightforward